# Tengo un formulario y el boton no me esta generando ninguna accion dejo el codigo con el cual estoy ejectutando

Tags: php

```
<div align="center">
                <input align="center" name="EnviarInfo" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" style="width: 50%" action='EnviarInfo' value="Asignar">
        </div>
    </form></center>

    <?

 if ($_POST[EnviarInfo])

 { 


    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","pcomp","KneTPuxJ77f4YLNX", "xxxx");  
    $causa_falla = $_POST['causa_falla'];
    $c1 = $_POST['c1'];
    $c2 = $_POST['c2'];
    $c3 = $_POST['c3'];
    $c4 = $_POST['c4'];
    $c5 = $_POST['c5'];
   $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $obs = $_POST['obs'];
   $par = $_POST['par'];

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","pcomp","KneTPuxJ77f4YLNX", "xxxx");  

  if ($_POST['estado'] == 'Rechazado'){
        $sql = "UPDATE 'avisos_auditados' set 'estado'='No es Falla' f_termino='$date' where id_aviso=$id_p";



    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

                echo "<script>alert('Cambios realizados', 'Asignar CFN')</script>"; 

            } else{

                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
            }

              $yourURL="ver_aviso_auditado.php?id=$aux";
              //echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
            echo"<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;url=$yourURL'/>"; 



    }
    else if ($_POST['estado'] == 'Aprobado'){

        if ($c1 == "" && $c2 == "" && $c3 == "" && $c4 == "" && $c5 == "" ) {

            echo "<script>alert('Debe ingresar una cuenta como minimo', 'Debe ingresar una cuenta')</script>";

        }else {

            $contadorCuentas = 0;

            if ($c1 == "" ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c2 == "" ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c3 == "" ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c4 == "" ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c5 == "" ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            $sql = "UPDATE avisos_auditados set estado='Es Falla', f_termino='$date' where id_aviso=$id_p";

            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO avisos (tipo_defecto, direccion, agencia, central, tipo_cable, cable, armario, cuenta1, cuenta2, cuenta3,cuenta4,cuenta5, fecha_ingreso, fecha_revisar_aviso, fecha_respuesta_aviso) 
                     VALUES ('$tipo_defecto','$direccion', '$agencia', '$central', '$central','$tipo_cable','$cable','$armario',cuenta1='$c1', cuenta2='$c2',cuenta3='$c3',cuenta4='$c4',cuenta5='$c5','$date','$date','$date')";

            if(mysqli_query($link, $sql) and mysqli_query($link, $sql2)){

                echo "<script>alert('Cambios realizados', 'Asignar CFN')</script>"; 

            } else{

                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
            }
            try {
                echo $_POST[EnviarInfo];
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "exepcion campturada:".$e->intl_get_error_message();

            }

              $yourURL="revisar_aviso_falla.php?id=$aux";
              //echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
            echo"<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;url=$yourURL'/>"; 

            }

    }


}


?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Qué acción quieres que te genere? Aquí parece que falta la extensión del archivo: `action='EnviarInfo'` ... ¿no debería ser **`action='EnviarInfo.php'`**? Sabiendo que si el archivo del action no está en la misma carpeta del script debes incluir la ruta correctamente indicando en qué carpeta está.

Answer (score 1):

en primer lugar creo que debes ver algunos videitos en youtube sobre consultas **SQL** y su sintaxys, por otra parte tu codigo tiene muchas fallas incluyendo comillas simples dentro de comillas simples, no comillas,conexion a la bases de datos duplicada innecesariamente etc...

mira como seria la sintaxys correcta para las sentencias **SQL**

```
//tu html correctamente quedaria asi
<center>
   <form action='EnviarInfo.php' method="post">

    <div align="center">
                    <input align="center" name="EnviarInfo" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" style="width: 50%"  value="Asignar">
            </div>
        </form>
    </center>
```

tu archivo **php** modificado

```
   <?php
//siempre pon tu conexion primero que todo para que tenga un uso mas global
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","pcomp","KneTPuxJ77f4YLNX", "xxxx"); 

//aqui teneis que poner Enviarinfo dentro isset para saver si esta definida
 if (isset($_POST["EnviarInfo"])) 



    $causa_falla = $_POST['causa_falla'];
    $c1 = $_POST['c1'];
    $c2 = $_POST['c2'];
    $c3 = $_POST['c3'];
    $c4 = $_POST['c4'];
    $c5 = $_POST['c5'];
   $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $obs = $_POST['obs'];
   $par = $_POST['par'];


  if ($_POST['estado'] == 'Rechazado'){
        $sql = "UPDATE avisos_auditados set estado='No es Falla' f_termino='".$date."' where id_aviso='".$id_p."'";



    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

                echo "<script>alert('Cambios realizados, Asignar CFN')</script>"; 

            } else{

                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
            }

              $yourURL="ver_aviso_auditado.php?id=$aux";
              //echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
            echo"<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;url=$yourURL'/>"; 



    }
    else if ($_POST['estado'] == 'Aprobado'){

        if ($c1 == "" && $c2 == "" && $c3 == "" && $c4 == "" && $c5 == "" ) {

            echo "<script>alert('Debe ingresar una cuenta como minimo ingresar una cuenta')</script>";

        }else {

            $contadorCuentas = 0;

            if ($c1 == "" ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c2 == "" ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c3 == "" ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c4 == "" ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c5 == "" ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            $sql = "UPDATE avisos_auditados set estado='Es Falla', f_termino='".$date."' where id_aviso='".$id_p."' ";

            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO avisos (tipo_defecto, direccion, agencia, central, tipo_cable, cable, armario, cuenta1, cuenta2, cuenta3,cuenta4,cuenta5, fecha_ingreso, fecha_revisar_aviso, fecha_respuesta_aviso) 
                     VALUES ('$tipo_defecto','$direccion', '$agencia', '$central', '$central','$tipo_cable','$cable','$armario',cuenta1='$c1', cuenta2='$c2',cuenta3='$c3',cuenta4='$c4',cuenta5='$c5','$date','$date','$date')";

            if(mysqli_query($link, $sql) and mysqli_query($link, $sql2)){

                echo "<script>alert('Cambios realizados, Asignar CFN')</script>"; 

            } else{

                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql:" . mysqli_error($link);
            }
            try {
                echo $_POST[EnviarInfo];
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "exepcion campturada:".$e->intl_get_error_message();

            }

              $yourURL="revisar_aviso_falla.php?id=$aux";
              //echo ("<script>location.href='".$yourURL."'</script>");
            echo"<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;url=$yourURL'/>"; 

            }

    }


}


?>
```

espero te sirva de ejempo saludos!

Comment: gracias fue de mucha ayuda :)